# List all keys added to keychain using `security add-generic-password`

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, security, keychain

Is there a command in `security` that lists the names of **all** keys that have been added to the keychain through `add-generic-password`?

I've tried, but it `find-generic-password` only ever returns one result as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2021-11-25, there is no flag in security to output only the `keys` so you have to get the whole list and then look for the relevant value:

```
security dump-keychain | awk -F'=' '/0x00000007/ { print $2 }'
```

Learn more about [awk pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Expression-Patterns.html).